# Location of pgadmin4 config_local.py on MacOS Mojave

Tags: macos, pgadmin-4

The pgAdmin4 documentation for [desktop deployment](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/3.6/desktop_deployment.html) states that custom configuration should be done in `config_local.py`. Unfortunately I cannot find where this file would/should be on a Mac.

Where on the Mac (Mojave) does the pgAdmin 4 config reside.

Specifically I want to enable keep-alive on the client side of the DB.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use command: sudo find / -name "config.py"

I found that the config.py is in this path on macos catalina:

/Library/PostgreSQL/12/pgAdmin 4.app/Contents/Resources/web/config.py

Comment: OP asked for LOCAL config, config.py should not be edit as docs says

Answer (score 8):

I found the location of the pgAdmin4 config file on my Mac (Mojave):

```
/Applications/pgAdmin 4.app/Contents/Resources/web
```

Unfortunately that did not help me any further with the underlying question, how to configure keep-alive for the connection to the DB. There is no such parameter in the `config.py`.

Comment: On macOS Big Sur, I created the file `config_local.py` in that directory and edited it to my liking. (Actually I copied `config_distro.py` to `config_local.py` in that directory and then edited it.) Now, I was working on another configuration not mentioned here, but mentioning in case it helps because this seems to be the correct directory.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create service file which holds that information
Ref: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/libpq-pgservice.html

Once the file is created with required connection parameters then you can provide the service name in pgAdmin4 for your database server.
Ref: https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/4.13/server_dialog.html

Click the Connection tab > Use the Service field to specify the service name